# First Post Review Display is Off

Tags: bug, status-completed

Anyone else seeing this?  The First Posts review screen seems to be pulling in the header/footer into the review content.

It doesn't appear to save, I just get "loading next item" forever after submitting.  Same in both Chrome & FireFox.

Close Votes and Suggested Edits seems to work fine.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I'm also getting this. SE Team must be working on some changes. They do have maintenance scheduled for tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not seeing this, must have been fixed

Comment: Yup, it is back to normal now.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345602/156631

Comment: Great, Thanks !